# Minimum symbol precedence

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, analysis, supremum-and-infimum

If you find $$(t-s)\alpha \wedge 1$$
for $t,s,\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ then what symbol has the precedence?
Do I need to calculate first $(\alpha \wedge 1)$ and then $(t-s)(\alpha \wedge 1)$ or $(t-s)\alpha$ and then calculate the minimum $(t-s)\alpha \wedge 1$ ?

Comment: What's the point of $\beta$? When you ask a question, remove the superfluous parts.

Comment: I'm not familiar with your notation in this context. I understand $\space(t-s)\alpha \wedge 1\space$ as containing an $and$ or $wedge$ symbol but I do not understand what it does $here$. I'm just a hobbyist. Can you help me get up to speed?

Comment: it's a minimum $a\wedge b = min(a,b)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no right or wrong answer - as it stands the notation is ambiguous. That being said, based off [your question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4247469/is-it-correct-the-estimate-of-the-following-integral) my guess is that $$(t-s) \alpha \, \wedge \, 1 $$ means $$((t-s) \alpha )\, \wedge \, 1 $$ i.e. $$\min \{ (t-s)\alpha,1 \}. $$

Comment: Ok thanks, and thanks for confirming the ambiguous notation.