# Is it correct the estimate of the following integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Let $\alpha >0, 1/3 >\beta>0, T>0$, $t,s \in [0,T]$
\begin{aligned}
    \int_{0}^{\alpha(t-s)} r^{-2 \beta} e^{-2 r} d r \\
 \leqslant c_{T}((t-s) \alpha \wedge 1)^{1-2 \beta}
\end{aligned}
for some $C=C_T>0$ constant independent of $\alpha,\beta$.

My question is: is the estimate correct? I don't understand why it is $\alpha \wedge 1$ and not just $\alpha$ on the rhs. It seems wrong to me, since if $\alpha$ is big then $\alpha \wedge 1=1$ and then $C_T$ must take into account also of the dependence on $\alpha$. What do you think?

Comment: Some assumptions are certainly missing or the integration bounds are wrong: if $\beta>\frac 12$, the integral, as written, clearly diverges to $+\infty$. So, please, check that you copied the statement correctly.

Comment: yes thanks I corrected: $\beta \leq 1/3$ even if $\beta \leq 1/2 $ for this integral should be ok

Comment: Are you sure that they meant $\alpha \wedge 1$ and not $((t-s) \alpha)\wedge 1$?